# Error: no module named gtk.glade

Tags: python, gtk

I researched and tried this for two days now and I cannot get gtk to work on **Windows 7** with **Python 3.4**! Whenever I launch my `.py` file on Python 3.4 with import gtk, I get No module named gtk! I installed **pygobject** but it did not help. Even gtk3-demo command works in the windows cmd prompt.

I finally got gtk to import (I think) by copying the GTK directory right to `C:\Python34\Lib`. But now I have a problem with `gtk.glade`.

Where is this? Where do I copy it from and to where?

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly using an outdated tutorial, see the [current Python GTK 3 tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for a more up-to-date reference.

In particular, the way to import GTK has changed in GTK3 to:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

And instead of libglade, you would use the newer `Gtk.Builder` class like so:

```
ui = Gtk.Builder()
ui.add_from_file("my_glade_file.glade")
```

(you still *develop* the UI using Glade, it is only how you access it from your program that has changed).